# CSS3 filter doesn't work on Opera,Internet Explorer,Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, browser, css-filters

CSS have command ***filter*** and it have many functions examples:

```
  filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: sepia(0);
  filter: saturate(1);
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  filter: invert(0);
  filter: opacity(1);
  filter: brightness(1);
  filter: contrast(1);
  filter: blur(0px);
```

Filter supporting Chrome 18+,Safari 6+. (Source: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/filters/)

I need use *grayscale, sepia, saturate, brightness, contrast, blur*. I can't use any of this because few browsers(ie,mozilla,opera) doesn't support **filter**

**My question:** Maybe this functions have alternatives or something else to get similar result like: *grayscale, sepia, saturate, brightness, contrast, blur*

What i try:
add prefix: `-moz-, -o-, -ms-`

Something from official microsoft website examples, but doesn't work :/ Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=50)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1); width=50%
```

**What's interesting is.** I found solutions for internet explorer: 6,7,8 (Source: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) i try test it for me internet explorer 11, but it's doesn't work. code:

```
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#4477a1'); /* IE6 & IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#81a8cb', endColorstr='#4477a1')"; /* IE8 */
```

I need to find a solution that operates on Mozilla, Opera, Internet Explorer at least with latest versions

Comment: filter is exclusively a IE thing it won't ever ever work in other browsers

Comment: Opera does support filters with `-webkit-` prefix. I am on Opera and [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/visual-effects-in-css3-using-filters) demo works fine for me.

Comment: Teo, my filter works on chrome and safari, but doesn't work on ie,mozilla and opera

Comment: @Teo: It *was* proprietary to IE for many years until the SVG WG decided to port SVG filters to CSS, which is what this question is about. `-ms-filter` remains proprietary to IE but I'm sure they can't wait to drop it in favor of SVG filters now.

Comment: I also have this issue and filter working on IE. DId you fixed it somehow @Asker? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mozilla Firefox**: [support without prefix is coming in Firefox 34 according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) (stable version currently at 32). For a few weeks, you'll need the SVG filter via url() if I understood well.

Note: if you support Firefox ESR - Extended Support Release - that may be deployed by quite a few IT departments and organizations, Fx 24 ESR won't be supported after october 2014 but Fx 31 ESR will be till mid or end 2015 I guess. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Extended_Support_Release))

Answer (score 2):

http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

From what I can tell, CSS Filter Effects are not supported in IE all the way up to IE v11. Firefox has partial support. Opera v24 and up have full support with -webkit- prefix.

Comment: Maybe Opera is okey, but basic problem is internet explorer and mozilla..